# Fusion Charts on Firefox caching xml when not wanted

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc-3, firefox, caching, fusioncharts

We are using fusion charts at work and they are using xml to set the data and style of the charts

We're not wanting to cache any of the data as it's potentially sensitive. this is fine in all browsers except Firefox...

Why is it only firefox that is doing this, how can we make it stop!!??

Why do people still insist on using FLASH!?!? Of all things?!

Comment: Have you looked on the fusion-charts forum? http://forum.fusioncharts.com/topic/33-how-do-i-stop-caching-of-the-xml-files/

Comment: it's... without using coarse language.. crap. it's a graveyard of unanswered questions

Comment: appart from the question you just linked to!!! :) thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

Try this to stop caching

```
chart1.setDataURL(escape("xmlfile.xml?currTime=" + getTimeForURL()));
/**
  * getTimeForURL method returns the current time 
  * in a URL friendly format, so that it can be appended to
  * dataURL for effective non-caching.
*/
 function getTimeForURL(){
 var dt = new Date();
 var strOutput = "";
 strOutput = dt.getHours() + "_" + dt.getMinutes() + "_" + dt.getSeconds() + "_" +    dt.getMilliseconds();
  return strOutput;
 }
```